# Node.js issue with twitter API/bot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to set up a twitter bot API, that creates a custom image. When I go to run the script I get the following error:

D:\TwitterBot\Node1\bot.js:39
                        media_ids: [id]
                        ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

My js file looks like this so far (redacted the API credentials for obvious reasons)

```js
console.log("The bot is starting...");

var Twit = require("twit");    

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         "...",
  consumer_secret:      "...",
  access_token:         "...",
  access_token_secret:  "...",
})

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');

function processing() {
 console.log('finished');
}

tweetIt();
//setInterval(tweetIt, 1000*60) //1 min

function tweetIt(){
 var cmd = 'processing-java --sketch=rainbow --run'
 exec(cmd, processing);

 function processing() {
  var filename = 'rainbow/output.png';
  var params = {
   encoding: 'base64'
  }
  var b64 = fs.readFileSync(filename, params);

  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64 }, uploaded);

  function uploaded(err, data, response) {
   var id = data.media_id_string;
   var tweet = {
       status: '#test'
       media_ids: [id]

   }
   T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);
  }

 }
}

function tweeted(err, data, response) {
 if (err) {
  console.log('fail');
 } else {
  console.log('pass');
 }
}
```

I'm not too sure where to start looking, everything seems to be fine in my eyes - so i'd be grateful if anyone can advise what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: add `}` at the end of `tweetIt` function

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with twitter API, it's just a `SyntaxError` you're missing a closing `}` at the end of `function tweetIt() {`

```
function tweetIt() {
    var cmd = 'processing-java --sketch="%cd%\\rainbow" --run'
    exec(cmd, processing);

    function processing() {
        var filename = 'rainbow/output.png';
        var params = {
            encoding: 'base64'
        }
        var b64content = fs.readFileSync(filename, params);

        T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, uploaded);
    }
} // This was missing
```

Or depending what you were trying to do:

```
 function tweetIt() {
    /* ... */
 } // This was missing

 function processing() {
    /* ... */
 }
```

### Update

> I've now got the following error after making that change:
>   D:\TwitterBot\Node1\bot.js:39 media_ids: [id] ^^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected identifier I've updated the original post with the new code

You're missing a comma `(,)` after `status` property.

```
function uploaded(err, data, response) {
    var id = data.media_id_string;
    var tweet = {
        status: '#test', // Missing comma (,)
        media_ids: [id]

    }
    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've now got the following error after making that change:

D:\TwitterBot\Node1\bot.js:39
                        media_ids: [id]
                        ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I've updated the original post with the new code

Comment: Updated answer, that should have been a new question, since you change the original one. And you should be able to understand those syntax errors by yourself, try installing a linter.